# Is there a way to access the "request" and "response" within a server side layout, page or component in nextjs13's app directory?

Tags: cookies, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components, nextjs-app-beta

I'm trying to apply server side authentication in a similar way to how `getServerSideProps()` works in the older `/pages` approach to nextjs.

However with this approach `getServerSideProps` takes a context parameter which contains both the `req` and `res` from the server. Which means we could attach headers to the response.

Is this context (or parts) accessible in the new `Server Components` within nextjs 13?

I know I can access cookies and headers for the request using the `next/cookies` and `next/headers` - is there a way to access the response? Current `cookies.set()` function doesn't work (throws an error), do I need have to wait for this to be implemented?

Comment: `next/cookies` doesn't support `cookies.set()` at the moment per the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cookies), but they're working on it

Comment: thanks, I figured it would be a case of it being beta rather than impossible, just wanted to confirm that really.